# Display in cell from Datatable all content from one List

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Actually i fed a datatable by a List.

I want to display in one cell another List from object and display all the content .

I never see this case before, it's possible to do that ?

Anyone can give me an exemple for help me ?

Thanks

Comment: do you want another collection of elements to be listed inside a datatable column ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using ui:repeat, for example:

```
<p:column>
    <ui:repeat value="#{listElement.someList}" var="listElem">
        <h:outputText value="#{listElem} " />
    </ui:repeat>
</p:column>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use  `<ui:repeat>`  to achieve that.

```
 <p:dataTable var="tab" value="#{list.l1}">
 <p:column>
       <ui:repeat value="#{accesslistin backing bean}" var="variable">
                      <h:outputText value="#{variable.watever}"/>
        </ui:repeat>
  </p:column>
 </p:dataTable>
```